# Magento 2 PWA : Get the CMS block content

Tags: magento2, pwa-studio

I need to get the content of the cms block without rendering. I need some operation with that content(append some text in middle or at the end & replace some text). After I complete my operations, I render it. Is there any way, if so any once can help me?

Answer (score 1):

First import and then add identifiers

```
import CmsBlockGroup from "@magento/venia-ui/lib/components/CmsBlock";
.
.
.
<CmsBlockGroup identifiers={'cms-block-name'}/>
```

I hope this will help every one.

Comment: will it work in venia pwa setup ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, even passing the CMS id it doesn't render the content, it just displays the Pagebuilder html, that default structure of it.

But checking in Apollo, in the request the data comes correctly, it's just not mounted on the front-end.

[image]

Graphql request
[image]

Answer (score 0):

add array []
<CmsBlockGroup identifiers={['cms-block-name']}/>